# DNS issue with strongSwan on Pop_OS 21.10

Tags: strongswan, pop-os, resolv.conf

I have installed `strongswan-starter` on Pop!_OS to connect to my workplace.

I have first installed it on Ubuntu (where everything worked perfectly fine) but decided to switch to Pop!_OS 21.10.

When I connect to the VPN on Pop!_OS, I can ping the remote network, but DNS is not working. When I look at `/etc/resolv.conf` I can see that the DNS nameservers have not been set, so this is obviously why DNS is not working.

On Ubuntu I had to install `resolvconf` manually, then restart the `strongswan-starter` and then I could see the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

On Pop_OS! `resolvconf` is installed nativley. Restarting `resolvconf.service` did not help.

Does anybody have an idea on how to get this to work?

**Edit:**

This is what the logs say (`/var/log/syslog`):

```
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os systemd[1]: Started strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf.
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os ipsec[2925]: Starting strongSwan 5.9.1 IPsec [starter]...
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.1, Linux 5.16.15-76051615-generic, x86_64)
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG]   loaded ECDSA private key from '/etc/ipsec.d/private/user.key'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[CFG] HA config misses local/remote address
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-aka eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam tnc-tnccs dhcp lookip error-notify certexpire led addrblock unity counters
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os ipsec[2925]: charon (2928) started after 20 ms
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 04[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'roadw'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 04[CFG]   loaded certificate "CN=user" from 'user.crt'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 04[CFG]   loaded certificate "CN=rw.vpn.company.ch" from 'rw.vpn.company.ch.cert.pem'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 04[CFG] added configuration 'roadw'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os charon: 06[CFG] received stroke: route 'roadw'
Apr 19 16:34:12 pop-os ipsec[2925]: 'roadw' routed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345503cde0 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicAppDisplay.cosmic-app-display:insensitive] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345609a8b0 StViewport:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345503cde0 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicAppDisplay.cosmic-app-display:insensitive] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345609a8b0 StViewport:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345068dc40 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicFolderButton.app-well-app cosmic-base-folder-button ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345503cde0 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicAppDisplay.cosmic-app-display:insensitive] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345609a8b0 StViewport:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345068dc40 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicFolderButton.app-well-app cosmic-base-folder-button ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x5634503bc420 Gjs_ui_iconGrid_BaseIcon.overview-icon overview-icon-with-label:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345503cde0 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicAppDisplay.cosmic-app-display:insensitive] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345609a8b0 StViewport:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345068dc40 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicFolderButton.app-well-app cosmic-base-folder-button ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x5634503bc420 Gjs_ui_iconGrid_BaseIcon.overview-icon overview-icon-with-label:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x563451883710 StBoxLayout:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345503cde0 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicAppDisplay.cosmic-app-display:insensitive] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345609a8b0 StViewport:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x56345068dc40 Gjs_pop-cosmic_system76_com_applications_CosmicFolderButton.app-well-app cosmic-base-folder-button ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x5634503bc420 Gjs_ui_iconGrid_BaseIcon.overview-icon overview-icon-with-label:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x563451883710 StBoxLayout:insensitive ("Library Home")] which is not in the stage.
...
```

I assume the relevant log entries are these, because these are the first that fail (and they do not appear on another system running Ubuntu with the same VPN configuration):

```
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Apr 19 16:34:20 pop-os gnome-shell[1540]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
```

Comment: Try reading the log.

Comment: Hi @ecdsa I have looked at the log (see updated post). I have tried searching for the error, but I cannot figure out what the problem is (I am relatively new to linux). Could you have a look at the logs?

Comment: The messages you pointed out should not matter at all (as you can see, they are issued by `gnome-shell`, not strongSwan's IKE daemon `charon`). Regarding the strongSwan log, it only shows loading the config, not actually initiating it. You have to either generate traffic that triggers the installed trap policy, change `auto=route` to `auto=start`, or manually initiate it via `ipsec up roadw`.

Comment: Oh thanks for your help, I figured it out! Turns out there was a missing symlink, I got it working, I will write up the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out thanks to the pointers of @ecdsa :)

Before reading the logs I had to initialize strongSwan with `ipsec up roadw`.

Then the logs in `/var/log/syslog` showed these entries:

```
Apr 19 22:27:08 pop-os charon: 16[IKE] installing DNS server X.X.X.X via resolvconf
Apr 19 22:27:08 pop-os charon: 16[IKE] resolvconf: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

I was able to fix the symbolic link according to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54888/resolvconf-u-gives-the-error-resolvconf-error-etc-resolv-conf-must-be-a-sym) on AskUbuntu:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Finally, initialize strongSwan with:

```
sudo ipsec up roadw
```

The problem is solved now, `/etc/resolv.conf` shows the proper nameservers and DNS is working.

**Edit:**

I have checked on a fresh install, apparently by default on Pop!_OS `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link to:

`../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

and not:

`../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`